# Linkedin - Publish Date "not found"

Tags: angular, linkedin-api

The [linked in post inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Ftuananh290895.github.io%2Fopen-graph%2F) near the bottom the section labeled providing the following feedback:
[image]

Can you help me with any solution to show the data for the publish date?
I assume this date comes from their internal scraping process. But I don't know API support for this.